# move cursor to next UITextField without click on next in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

> How can I move control to next text field automatically after entering 10 digit.

Comment: Using become first responder

Answer (score 4):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
NSString *currentString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
int length = [currentString length];
if (length > 10) {
   [yourNextTextfield becomeFirstResponder];
     return NO; // add the line 
}
return YES;
}
```

**choice no-2**

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
 if (newLength >10)
    {
        [yournextTextfield becomeFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
 return YES;
}
```

**Swift**

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
var currentString: String = textField.text!.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
var length: Int = currentString.characters.count
if length > 10 {
    yourNextTextfield.becomeFirstResponder()
    return false
    // add the line
}
return true
}
```

**Another Choice**

```
   func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
var newLength: Int = textField.text!.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
if newLength > 10 {
    yournextTextfield.becomeFirstResponder()
    return false
}
return true
}
```

Comment: the problem with this code is when I enter 10th digit , the 10th digit get inserted into next field and it should not be.
just cursor should move to next field not any digit.

Comment: - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    
    
    
    NSString *currentString = [creditCardField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSUInteger length = [currentString length];
    if (length >=11) {
        [card_monthField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}

Comment: try change this length >=11 into length >10

Comment: just wait I check and tell to you

Comment: Good one.. but the next field not taking any input.

Comment: I tried here it worked for me fine bro, put the condition like if (textfield ==currentrtextfield){// do the following work} else if {// do your stuff}, customize your self bro

Comment: a little problem is that cursor does not move to next field automatic after 10 digit.it move when I enter 11th digit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84141/discussion-between-anand-prakash-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: simple bro decrease the one count

Comment: 11th digit should be in next field

Answer (score 2):

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField{

     NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;

     // Try to find next responder
     UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];

     if (nextResponder) {

     // Found next responder, so set it.
     [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];

     } else {

     // Not found, so remove keyboard.
     [textField resignFirstResponder];
     }
  return NO; // We do not want UITextField to insert line-breaks.
}
```

if you have multiple textfield you can also use this

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*) textField 
{
    if (textField == txt1){
    [txt1 resignFirstResponder];
    [txt2 becomeFirstResponder];
   }
   if (textField == txt2){
    [txt2 resignFirstResponder];
   }
    return YES;
}
```

Don't forget to add delegate **UITextFieldDelegate** to your UITextfield